# About xml serialization in c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I was asked the following question in interview:

- Explain XML Serialization.

I have no idea what XML Serialization is. I looked at some sites, but I couldn't find any (short & clear) explanation about XML Serialization.

Could someone explain what XML Serialization is?  It would help so I can have a clear picture on XML Serialization and be ready to face future interviews with confidence whenever this question is asked..

Comment: Please have a look at this document : **http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21121/Generic-XML-Serialization-in-C**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have a class like this:

```
Public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

and an object of this class like this:

```
Person Student = new Person();
Student.FirstName = "John";
Student.LastName = "Smith";
Student.age= 24;
```

Then when you xml serialize the object Student. You will get as an output an XML file with the following:

```
<Person>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
     <LastName >Smith</LastName >
    <age>24</age>  
</Person>
```

You can deserialize the XML to get the original object as an output.

So it is kind of a conversion between classes and XML
BTW XML files are usualy text files

Comment: i guess the Root element name will be the class name instead of the object name

Comment: Yes sorry I fixed it. I written it fast so didn't pay attention

Answer (score 2):

That means converting an object to XML form so that it can be transported over HTTP & Other transport protocols or Store it for Other purposes. `XML` is considered as a data transport format between different systems (developed even in different languages). You can send data from one app to another app in XML format. Most of the WebServices returns data in XML format. A variety of clients can access these webservice method without worrying about what platform/language the webservice is writn in because it is simply going to deal with the XML form of the data coming in.

More reading : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx

Comment: XML does not have to be transported, it can simply be saved to disk to serve as configuration file or anything at all.

Comment: @Mert: Yea. I said it **can be** transported.

Comment: Why HTTP?  There are plenty of other protocols over which Xml can be transported, not to mention that it will be just as often stored as it is transported.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk: You are correct. WIll update the note to mention your point. Thanks for jumping in.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Youssef's answer, you can also specify how the serialized XML will be written by doing the following:

```
[XmlRoot("RootElementsName")]
Public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

this will produce XML like:

```
<RootElementsName>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
     <LastName >Smith</LastName >
    <age>24</age>  
</RootElementsName>
```

You can read more about the various XML modifiers here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e123c76w.

Comment: +1 because I learned something new

Answer (score 1):

The definition on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) is about as good as it gets:

> Serialization is the process of converting a data structure or object state into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link) and "resurrected" later in the same or another computer environment.

*Xml* Serialization is just serialization [Xml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml) as the storage and transport format.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to understand why serialization matters in C#. We will have C# object when we run our c# application. At some point of time you may want to persist it so that you can use it later time. For example if you are writing an application like firefox downloader. When u close it, if u are in mid of download it, you can reload it with the last closed status.

So if you want to persist the status in your harddisk that is called binary serialization. If you want to send your object across wires that is called xml serialization